# Implementation of Unlikelihood Training loss in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function

I am trying to implement the Unlikelihood Training loss that was proposed in this research paper: [NEURAL TEXT DEGENERATION WITH UNLIKELIHOOD TRAINING](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.04319.pdf). This loss is an updated version of the negative log-likelihood loss (NLLLOSS).

The main idea of this loss is that it avoids unwanted tokens during the training process.
[image]

This is my code:

```
def NLLLoss(logs, targets, c, alpha=0.1):
    out = torch.zeros_like(targets, dtype=torch.float)
    for i in range(len(targets)):
        # out[i] = logs[i][targets[i]] # The original implementation
        out[i] = alpha * (1 - logs[i][c[i]]) * logs[i][targets[i]]
    return -out.sum()/len(out)
```

The commented line is the original NLLLoss implementation. This code well, but I was wondering, is this implementation correct?

Answer (score 0):

No, log(1-x) does not equal 1 - log(x).
I think what need is [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/unlikelihood_training/blob/944465589c0fab534fe6d14a5db2850ddeee43ce/custom/candidate_penalty_ce_loss.py#L64).

Comment: Even in this code they are doing 1-log(x)!

Comment: @Minions No, They do  1-probs and then they compute the log of the outcome.